# Deadlock graph in SQL server profiler shows mutual lock on the same clustered key

Tags: sql-server, indexing, deadlock, sql-server-profiler

I am trying to identify the reason of deadlock using SQL Server Profiler.
Here's the deadlock graph:
[image: Deadlock graph]
Both statements are **inserts** followed by `select scope_identity();`
Actually a have 2 concurrent processes that repeatedly do **insert-select_identity** in a cycle.

What would i expect is that *insert* takes exclusive lock over the *clustered index* and *select* takes a shared lock of the *non-clustered index*, and then they wait for each other to release their respective indeces.

What i see is that both processes wait for the same resource to be released - the clustered index. How can this be? The particular recourse should belong either to one process or to another. What do i miss here?
thanks to all in advance.

Edited: yes, isolation level is Serializible.
PS: probably, my assumption about the shared lock on non-clustered index was wrong as far as my select does not contain a `where` statement

Edit2:
here is the part of xml:

```
 <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594148028416" dbid="29" objectname="<confidential>" indexname="PK_WP_Inbound_StockTransactionLine" id="lock9641700" mode="RangeS-S" associatedObjectId="72057594148028416">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process8e09288" mode="RangeS-S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process991ce08" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594148028416" dbid="29" objectname="<confidential>" indexname="PK_WP_Inbound_StockTransactionLine" id="lock9641700" mode="RangeS-S" associatedObjectId="72057594148028416">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process991ce08" mode="RangeS-S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process8e09288" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
```

According to this, i thinks that it is **Range scans caused by SERIALIZABLE isolation** (googled that). But still, i don't understand how does this happen and what is the recommended remedy.

Comment: What isolation level are you using? serializable? If so any reason for that?

Comment: yes, i forgot to say that, sorry. I've edited the post

Comment: post the deadlock XML, not the image. The image is incomplete,  misleading and often wrong.

Comment: You are most definitely dealing with different rows on the clustered index. Post the complete XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider following code being called from two parallel transactions(T1 and T2) accessing same record.

```
Read LastRow
Insert AtLastRow
```

Lets say context switch happens at `Read`. So sequence of operations is

```
T1 Read LastRow
T2 Read LastRow
T2 Insert AtLastRow // This will wait for T1 to finish.
T1 Insert AtLastRow // This will wait for T2 to finish. Hence deadlock!
```

Above read will take `Range S-S` lock. Insert at last also needs `Range I-N` which is not compatable with existing `Range S-S` lock held by other transactions. Hence it waits.

There can be multiple ways to solve this problem.

1. Use **read committed** as overall isolation level and not serializable.
   This will prevent taking Range locks.
2. Read with **update lock** (UPDLOCK). This will take exclusive update
   lock in 1st place. Hence other transaction will wait at Read itself.
3. **Avoid the read and insert/update pattern**. Just straight go ahead
   with insert/update and let it fail.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: 3. Avoid the read and insert/update pattern. Then how do i handle the fails? ie. i need to do smth else (say, display a specific message) in case when the record already exists. Should i just w8 for exception? and then what? parse the exception data to identify its exact reason? Besides, why should insert/update fail? Consider a situation when i need to check business logic constraints, not the data-model constraints. Probably, the solution is also to move the read op-n out of transaction. But in our case this is 2much refactoing, so i'll change the isolation lvl as a workaround. thank you =)

Comment: @ArturUdod lets say you read a row with key = 10 and increment value. You can either read the value and then update it or go ahead and update. If the key doesn't exist, above update will fail. Now if you detect failure, you insert key 10 with value 1. Does this help?

Comment: yeah, i got it. But, as i said: Let us assume that i only want to increment a value if it is less then 100. If it is already 100, then i want to display a message. Off cource, there can be a "check" constraint, but that's an easy example. I might have a far more complex validation business logic and i realy need to perform a read before modifying data.

Comment: @ArturUdod in that case, go with 2nd option. "Read with update lock (UPDLOCK)."

Comment: Actually, in my case there will be no danger if i switch the isolation level to read-commited just for this particular case. Phantom reads are unlikely to happen (just because the server logic prevents this). Thank you for your response.